# Newman report generation works locally but not from CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, newman

I have a GitLab CI job running a series of Postman requests using a custom environment. I'm using Newman to run them alongside the [newman-reporter-htmlextra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra) npm plugin to generate a test report.

The job looks like the following:

```
postman-tests:
  stage: postman-tests
  image: 
    name: wojciechzurek/newman-ci
  before_script:
    - cd ci/tests/postman
    - npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
  script:
    - newman run Non-regression_tests.postman_collection.json -e Tests.postman_environment.json \
      --reporters htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export newman-results.html
    - ls -la # Check report generation
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - newman-results.html
  allow_failure: true
```

When I run newman on my mac (newman 4.5.0), the requests and associated tests run properly and the report is generated. However, the job fails and the report is not generated:

```
 $ newman run Non-regression_tests.postman_collection.json -e Tests.postman_environment.json --reporters htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export newman-results.html --color

Uploading artifacts...

WARNING: newman-results.html: no matching files    
ERROR: No files to upload                          
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It seems that the issue may be caused by the testing series in itself rather than the report generation, as the job fails even when I don't generate the report.

I tried different runners: Docker with official newman images, SSH and shell over machines where I had installed newman (version 4.5.6) and the htmlextra reporter beforehand. All fail.
   It's interesting to note that the tests series and report generation **both succeed when run locally on the machines** behind the SSH and shell runners, but they do fail when launched from GitLab CI.

What did I forget/do wrong that prevents the test report generation from GitLab CI?

Comment: Does it work with just the CLI reporter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `.yml` for testing, look like this - It's very basic but I've just run it again and it was running fine:

```
stages:
    - test

newman_tests:
    stage: test
    image: 
        name: postman/newman_alpine33
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - newman --version
        - npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
        - newman run collection.json -e environment.json --reporters cli,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export testReport.html
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
            - testReport.html
```

One thing that I do have is `entrypoint: [""]` in the `image` block.